# Is FFMPEG download the file before processing?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I am working on FFMPEG, I read that http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/ article which I understand that FFMPEG doesn't download the file before processing, FFMPEG play the file through ffmplayer or any other player, I want to exactly make sure about FFMPEG,  that how it works?

1) It can download the file first and then make instance

OR

2) The file play and during play through FFMPEG Player make instance or conversion

Which point is correct?

If someone knows that, it will be very helpful for others and also me .. :) Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but usually a video encoder doesn't have to load the whole file into memory first. It should be able to process it *during* loading it. That's what a usual video *player* does, too.

Comment: @scai thanks scai.. I aslo think so that it doesn't download the file, it's creating instance through streaming

Comment: Streaming is also downloading.

Answer (score 0):

[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org) is a media processing utility. Like most Unix tools, you give it an input to produce an output. It does not grab sources on its own so, no, it will not download anything by itself.

> Read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg) for more information about on ffmpeg.
>   
>   Alternatively, run `man ffmpeg`!